# Is there a way to use wms like a tiled map service in sharpmap?

Tags: wms, .net, sharpmap

In sharpmap , is it possible to load a default wms like a tiled map service?

I was able to use a WMS but currently it loads the map as a single image.

I desire a behavior  like OpenLayers 3.

Edit:

My attempt with BruTile:

```
      const String url = @"http://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?dummy=dummy"; //dummy is needed because BruTile appends every parameter with ampersand

        BruTile.TileSchema schema = new BruTile.TileSchema();
        schema.Srs = "EPSG:25832";
        schema.Format = "image/png"; 
        schema.Axis = BruTile.AxisDirection.Normal;
        schema.Name = "UTM32";
        schema.Height = 256;
        schema.Width = 256;
        schema.OriginX = 271930.43;
        schema.OriginY = 5209532.85;
        schema.Extent = new BruTile.Extent(271930.43,5209532.85, 956095.08,6111268.07);

     Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        parameters.Add("STYLES", String.Empty);

        var request = new BruTile.Web.WmscRequest(new Uri(url), schema, new List<String> { "OSM-WMS" }, new List<String>(), parameters, "1.1.1");
        var provider = new BruTile.Web.WebTileProvider(request);
        var tileSrc = new BruTile.TileSource(provider , schema);
```

var layer1 = new SharpMap.Layers.TileLayer(tileSrc, "OSM");
            layer1.SRID = 25832;

That is what I have tried so far, but it does not work. Sharpmap shows nothing, not even an exception.

```
var ti = new BruTile.TileInfo();
ti.Extent = new BruTile.Extent(271930.43, 5209532.85, 956095.08, 6111268.07);
var uri = request.GetUri(ti).ToString();
```

This gives me a valid wms request, but I get a 407 Proxy Exception when I try the following.

```
 var ti = new BruTile.TileInfo();
 ti.Extent = new BruTile.Extent(271930.43, 5209532.85, 956095.08, 6111268.07);
 var tile = provider.GetTile(ti);
```

In Shapmap it is possible to configure a Proxy for SharpMap.Layers.WmsLayer but not for SharpMap.Layers.TileLayer.
Is there another way to set up a proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, either an ordinary tile layer (1) or a WMS accessed through a tile protocol (2). In both cases you could use BruTile.

1) SharpMap uses BruTile for its tile layers. You could add OpenStreetMap like this: 
`mapBox1.Map.BackgroundLayer.Add(
   new SharpMap.Layers.TileAsyncLayer(BruTile.Web.OsmTileSource(), "OSM"));`

Which I copied from this [SharpMap Sample](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918221216/https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorial%20-%20Example%204%3a%20Adding%20a%20Tiled%20layer%20as%20Background&referringTitle=SharpMap%20Tutorial)

2) In case you want to access a WMS in a tiled way then BruTile's WmscRequest can be used. It can access a WMS-C tile sources but also an ordinary WMS. The WMS-C requests are OGC compliant WMS requests constrained to the tile schema. There is a sample here in the [BruTile repo](https://github.com/BruTile/BruTile/blob/master/Samples/BruTile.Samples.Common/TileSourceForWmsSample.cs)

Comment: what I meant was not using tiles but splitting a single wms request into several partial requests.
I think it becomes visible in this example [link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/wms-no-proj.html?q=wms)

Comment: So that is the second option. Take a look at this sample: https://github.com/BruTile/BruTile/blob/master/Samples/BruTile.Samples.Common/TileSourceForWmsSample.cs. In what projection is your map?

Comment: The projection of my map is EPSG:25832 (UTM Zone 32). I think I need my own TileSchema object. I have added my attempts to the original post. It seems like they are a few differences between the newest BruTile version and the one used by sharpmap.